# Extend python staticmethod in other class

Tags: python, class

I have two classes which are responsible for some calculations. In first class I have calculateStatisticalFeatures static method which calculate come stuff and returns a DataFrame for me. In other class I would like to do almost the same but add one more calculation basing on the same new input data from second class. I found something like decorators but somehow I was not able to use it.

Method in first class:

```
@staticmethod
def calculateStatisticsFeatures(self, inputData) -> pd.DataFrame:
    #some calculations
    features = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[skewn, kurt, entropyVal, meanCalc]]), columns=['skewness', 'kurtosis','entropy', 'meanCalc'])
    return features
```

I was trying to use decorator like this to extend my first class method in second class but I can't paste the data.

```
@firstClass.calculateStatisticalFeatures(self.inputData)
def TestDecor(self):
    # new calculation
```

Is it somehow possible to add this calculations to second class? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Err honestly, why makes things static, when you want to do inheritance?

Comment: I used staticmethod because I don't need in instantiate first class. I just want to reuse one method from second class and add new functionality to it.

Comment: Yeah, and that is were static gets nasty. If you want inherit things, then static is an obstacle ... so rather consider to improve change your design, instead of working around the flaws of static.

Comment: Why is `self` as a variable in the staticmethod(calculateStatisticsFeatures)

Comment: @GhostCat first I need to learn how to change :) I am guite beginner in Python :)

Comment: @Vassago As far as I understand it is necessary to use this method later in first class so I added it into each method. Withoud self in methods I had an errors

Comment: You use self when you have non-static methods? I guess the real answer here: get yourself a good book on python and OO programming ;-)

Comment: #GhostCat Ok thanks. I understood that self is not accessible when I call this method from other place. I think I will remove static and just try split my class into two classes and inherit what I need. What book would you recommend as good?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed the staticmethod and just inherited second class. I was not aware that in Python we can inherit from classes in one class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
>>> import functools
>>> 
>>> class A():
...     @staticmethod
...     def test(func):
...             @functools.wraps(func)
...             def wrapper(*args, **kw):
...                     # features = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[skewn, kurt, entropyVal, meanCalc]]), columns=['skewness', 'kurtosis','entropy', 'meanCalc'])
...                     print(kw.get("inputData"))
...                     return func(*args, **kw)
...             return wrapper
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     @A.test
...     def testb(self, **kw):
...             print('test')
... 
>>> 
>>> B().testb(inputData="inputData")
inputData
test
```

Comment: Thank you for this. After I analyzed all comments, as I wrote I will change my code and remove static.